# ASP.NET UpdatePanel & TabIndex with IE8 issue

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, updatepanel, cross-browser

The sample Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET 3.5 project: [SOURCE CODE](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6uh3_tQ_xBCZ0hGVGstMzNIdFU)

### **Code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="Server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true" ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Debug" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div runat="server">
            test
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="UIDataChanged" />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TB2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="UIDataChanged" />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TB3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="UIDataChanged" />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TB4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="UIDataChanged" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Counter"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Basically I'm in the process of transitioning an application from IE6 to IE8. I have come across a scenario that I cannot work out. I've looked everywhere and discovered a few articles but nothing was detailed enough.

Basically in the sample project you will find 4 text boxes each is configured to `AutoPostBack="true"` and fires a sample `OnTextChange="UIDataChanged"` event.

I **forced** IE8 render mode using: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

### **To Reproduce Error:**

*NOTE: I will refer to text box 1 through to 4 as TB1, TB2 and so on.*

- Fire up IE8 and TAB to TB1 where you enter some text.
- Press TAB again and you will notice that this fires a postback and returns the cursor to TB1. Note: I am not doing anything fancy to hold onto cursor location yet.
- Press TAB again brings you to TB2 where you enter some text.
- After pressing TAB one more time, another postback occurs and the cursor jumps to TB3.
  But this is the issue: No further editing can  happen and if you continuously TAB you will no longer travel any of the textboxes.

### **Update 1:**

Tested the above in Visual Studio 2010 and IE9 Browser.

**Test Case 1:**

- Browser Mode: IE=9
- Framework: 4.0
- Result - Tabbing on text field works as expected

**Test Case 2:**

- Browser Mode: IE=9
- Framework: 3.5
- Result - Tabbing on text field works as expected

**Test Case 3:**

- Browser Mode: IE=8
- Framework: 4.0
- Result - Broken tabbing after 2nd TextBox

**Test Case 4:**

- Browser Mode: IE=8
- Framework: 3.5
- Result - Broken tabbing after 2nd TextBox

*Based on the above findings, it seems that the issue is possibly within the Internet Explorer Rendering Engine.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the findings I've come to the conclusion that this is most definitely an IE8 rendering issue. It is behaving differently to IE7 and IE9.

Based on further investigation the difference between IE7 and IE8 in terms of rendering is also too much to actually enforce IE7 mode.
Enforcing IE7 mode will fix the issue for the tabbing but may introduce further complexities depending on other styling "fixes" to accommodate IE8.

For future updates if Internet Explorer 9 does become available or is part of the standard operating environment for every user then I would suggest that IE9 rendering or IE'edge' is enforced for standards compliance.